# how to create a button in html/javascript/css that when clicked opens a sample web page within a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Im writing a simple color picker website for a class where the user inputs rgb, hsl, or hex# and when clicking a button, generates the colors in 6 swatches, 6 colors being the main one, complementary light and dark variants, and opposite color on the color wheel spectrum, etc. then there has to be a button that when clicked, loads a sample web page with the 6 colors implemented into that sample website, so the user can "view" the colors he/she chose on a website, like a template chooser type of deal. I just want some insight on how to create that,  obviously I am writing the sample website right now but I have no clue how to set that up in my javascript code or my html. if you have an idea on how to approach it please let me know. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an Iframe tag inside you page, change the src of iframe on button click.

```
    function changeurl(e) {
            $('#iframe').attr('src', 'http://www.w3schools.com');
            return false;
        }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on using jQuery, you could load another page using [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
      // .result is the container selector for the loaded page
      // data is the html of ajax/test.html
      $('.result').html(data); 
      alert('Load was performed.');
    });
});
```

Markup:

```
<div class="result"></div>
```

This will put the contents of `ajax/test.html` into the div with class `result`.

Comment: i am using firebug for this assignment and i get   $.get('ajax/a-snippet.html', function(data) {  is not a function

Comment: You are probably missing a reference to jquery.

Comment: oh i didnt read ur first post. I am not using jquery. :/ I actually figured it out though! thank you youve helped a lot.