# insert an html file into a DIV id in my main html file using javascript and AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, html

on an assignment I need to have a button that, when clicked, inserts content from another external html file that I have written. A snippet if you will. I don't want to use iframes, so Im stuck. I dont really know how to do this,  this is the javascript code I have currently:

**html:**

```
<div id = "snippet"></div>
<button id = "generate">generate</button>
```

**js:** (ignore the first 3 lines, those are for other methods)

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
    $('submit').observe('click',alertHSL);
    $('submit1').observe('click',alertRGB);
    $('submit2').observe('click',alertHex);
    $('generate').observe('click',loadSnippet);
});

function loadSnippet() {
    $("#snippet").load("snippet-b.html");
}
```

but when I run it in firefox (with firebug to debug it) it keeps saying that    `$("#snippet").load("snippet-b.html"); is = null`. how do I get this to work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to create a button in html/javascript/css that when clicked opens a sample web page within a webpage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511698/how-to-create-a-button-in-html-javascript-css-that-when-clicked-opens-a-sample-w)

Comment: You already asked this question, and I answered with same approach as Soc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the same approach with the equivalent get function:

```
$.get('snippet-b.html', function(data) {
    $('#snippet').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

If this don't get you closer you can load the debug version of jquery and add a breakpoint to see which objects are null.